# Minimal GDBus client

Tags: c, linux, dbus

I've been trying to make a simple program that does some of what bluetoothctl does, but automatically. It needs to not be GPL'd, so I can't just copy bluetoothctl's source. The biggest stumbling block has been just getting a simple D-Bus program to work. Since I'm targeting an embedded system (albeit a fairly powerful one) I can't afford to run Python or use just any programming language.

I've seen several questions here and loads of web sites with pointers to [obsolete things](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-glib/) or broken links or [documentation](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/index.html) that says I'm "signing up for some pain." How is there not a simple minimal example that sets up a D-Bus connection?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Makefile:

```
LIBS=gio-2.0
CFLAGS=-O0 -ggdb3 `pkg-config --cflags $(LIBS)`
LDFLAGS=`pkg-config --libs $(LIBS)`

.PHONY: clean
default: gdbus-example
gdbus-example: gdbus-example.o
    gcc $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

%.o: %.c
    gcc $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o gdbus-example
```

And here's a minimal C file to build with it that connects and watches for bluez:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>

void name_appeared(GDBusConnection *connection,
                   const gchar *name,
                   const gchar *name_owner,
                   gpointer user_data)
{
    printf("Name appeared: %s\n", name);
    printf("Owned by: %s\n", name_owner);
}

void name_vanished(GDBusConnection *connection,
                   const gchar *name,
                   gpointer user_data)
{
    printf("Name vanished: %s\n", name);
}

int main(void)
{
    GMainLoop *loop;
    GError *error;
    guint name;

    loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    name = g_bus_watch_name(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM,
                            "org.bluez", // 
                            G_BUS_NAME_WATCHER_FLAGS_NONE,
                            name_appeared,
                            name_vanished,
                            NULL,
                            NULL);

    g_main_loop_run(loop);
}
```

And here's a sample terminal session where I restarted the bluetooth service:

```
$ ./gdbus-example 
Name appeared: org.bluez
Owned by: :1.16
Name vanished: org.bluez
Name appeared: org.bluez
Owned by: :1.1152
```

Here is the [gio documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.56/index.html), which includes GDBus. It covers how to build and initialize GDBus programs. The DBus project points to the [high level](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html) and [low level](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-lowlevel.html) API docs.